# How do I verify a file copy in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to Linux (my Windows system drive died and I can't reinstall Windows, so I am trying a Ubuntu [live USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB)).

I am trying to clear a drive so I can install Ubuntu properly, so I have copied a directory full off stuff to back up from the drive to another drive. Now all I want to do is verify this copy has worked (by reading both copies and making sure they match byte for byte - I don't care about metadata).

As I'm running off a live USB, I want as little setup as possible,

I have tried the top answer in *[How can I calculate an MD5 checksum of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657232/how-can-i-calculate-an-md5-checksum-of-a-directory)*.

And it does not work. For some reason, the scan (and [du](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) for that matter) just skips a bunch of files in one of the copies (both drives are NTFS, BTW)

I can't get diffmerge to install. I tried installing [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) and that just hung (it’s 57 GB of data).

Either a direct compare of data, or something that will checksum a directory (file contents, but not meta data) like the SHA tools that come with [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) on Windows is fine.

Comment: Yeah the du weirdness was a separate issue I had when trying other things.

Comment: I think the reason that SO answer didnt work is because it fails if 2 different files have the same md5 (which I guess would happen if you have copies of the same file in different locations, or 0 length files).  In the end I just output the list of files with their hashes to a txt file, then diffed the txt files, ignoring 'moved lines'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command:

```
diff -r path/to/source-dir path/to/your-copy-dir
```

The output will tell you if directories are different or identical.

Comment: I don't think this checks the file contents byte for byte tho?

Comment: @matt no, it checks byte-for-byte

Comment: Thanks! it appears you are right, it seemed to be running *very* quickly when I ran it on two 60GB folders though, thats why I assumed it didn't. will double check

Comment: Couldn't it produce an *impractical* large amount of output? Shouldn't it be told to be somewhat quiet?

Comment: @PeterMortensen OP needs to _veryify_ and if they are really identical, it will be quiet. Otherwise, dirs are not identical. If there is a difference, verbose output can help.